# rentlinx featured property remove duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have displayed the featured property listing using rentlinx.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.[TagName].rentlinx.com/FeaturedPropertyJS.aspx?template=http://www.rentlinx.com/External/CalvoFeatured.xsl&ref=1"></script>
```

I want this featured property scroll via owl carousel.

```
<div class="owl-item"><div class="each-properties"> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.[TagName].rentlinx.com/FeaturedPropertyJS.aspx?template=http://www.rentlinx.com/External/CalvoFeatured.xsl&amp;ref=1"></script>
</div>

<div class="owl-item"><div class="each-properties"> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.[TagName].rentlinx.com/FeaturedPropertyJS.aspx?template=http://www.rentlinx.com/External/CalvoFeatured.xsl&amp;ref=2"></script>
</div>
```

Scroll are working now. But the properties are repeated to display. How ca I remove duplicate items?

For more information please refer the below link.

https://www.rentlinx.com/products/website-integration

Answer (score 0):

The featured properties are chosen at random. Make sure you have a different "ref" number at the end of each src attribute like this:

`http://www.[TagName].rentlinx.com/FeaturedPropertyJS.aspx?template=http://www.rentlinx.com/External/CalvoFeatured.xsl&amp;ref=2`

Note the "ref=2" at the end. Each snippet you include should have a different number to avoid the script getting cached and the same property being returned. Other than that, you would just need to make sure your client's RentLinx account has enough properties so it's not likely for there to be a duplicate chosen at random.

Comment: I already used different number like ref=1, ref=2, ref=3.... at the end